# Call ASP.Net Page_Load from a background job in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am using hangfire to run a background job in .Net.. I have a web forms page lets say at Charts/PricingChart.aspx..I wanted to know how I can call the Page_Load method of this page from my background job.

I can create an instance of the Page `PricingCharts p = new PricingCharts();`

but how do I make it go through the Page_Load lifecycle. I have data on that page which is cached on first visit but I was wondering if I can call that page through a background job then the cache will automatically be there without any user hitting the site. Page is secured by auth which I can bypass in the background job.

Comment: Would it be better to use a cron/scheduled task to curl your website to seed that data?

Comment: The Load method only gets called when the form is constructed.  If you have code that gets called after the constructor put it into a different method so you can called the code more than once.

Comment: How about creating an ashx handler (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/what-is-an-ashx-file-handler-or-web-handler/) and then put the caching code in the ProcessRequest method of the handler. Then, you can call execute a GET request to the ashx url from hangfire